# How do I fix my recycle bin that doesn't show the deleted items?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

The icon shows that it's full. I just deleted stuff, so I know that it's full. But when I open it, it doesn't show the deleted items. The only option I have is to restore them or empty them.

Help me out. It's VERY VERY important for me to fix this problem since I use this workstation for my studio purposes.

P.S. It's a Windows 7 Ultimate (x86) machine.

Comment: It doesn't show any items, but there's an option to restore them?!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yes, that's exactly correct.  There's items in the Recycle Bin, but when opened, you can't see anything.  You can, however, click the restore all items button to put *everything* back.  I have the exact same issue (in Win 7 Pro) on one of my systems at home and would love to know a solution to it.

Comment: No solutions so far. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Okay, I found a fix. All I had to do was:**

- Open a command prompt with administrator privilege.
- In the command prompt, type `rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.bin` and press Enter. [*NOTE: For the other hard drive letters, substitute `C:` for the other hard drive letter instead. For example: `rd /s /q E:\$Recycle.bin`*]
- Close command prompt window.
- Refresh the desktop. [*NOTE: The Recycle Bin should be all right by now. If not, then repeat these steps for any other hard drive letter that you have.*]

I helped myself. Hope, I helped some of you as well.

Answer (score 1):

That means that if you have a drive with two partitions, you need to do the same with the other partition.

For instance I dual boot XP and 7.  I had to do this for both XP and 7.  Then it worked.

Also, you can just delete the folder in the Explorer window, rather than go to a command prompt.